# How do you put JSON into environment variables?

Tags: json, environment-variables

I have a Google Analytics API JSON Key (a json file containing credential information). It should be stored as environment variables. How do you do that? I think I have two options.

1. Encode JSON in Base64 and store it as single key:value environment variable pair.
2. List all key and value pairs into environment variables.
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store entire JSON objects in your .env file as long as you properly handle the double quotes.

- Escape the double quotes with a backslash (\")
- Wrap the JSON object with single quotes